# Multi-colored stone-like procedural material

Tags: texturing, materials, procedural

I am trying to recreate this:

[image]

color pattern in blender, but I am unable to do so.

For a while now I've been orbitting around something in this fashion:

[image]

But I couldn't make it look any better. I tried using voronoi texture instead of noise, I tried different colors, rougness/scale values, different textures combination. I also tried to "normalize" black texture before plugging it to Color Ramp, in order to be able to use whole ramp instead of tiny bit of it, but I was unsuccesfull too.

Any help with bringing it closer to the reference image would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is it you don't like about your alternative?  Instead of the color ramp have you considered mixing multiple colors?

Comment: Alternative looks cool too, but I think I'd still prefer to be able to create original material. I got so "entangled" in this way of doing this material, that I forgot about mixing colors. I'l give it a try tomorrow, thanks.

Comment: If you see the original picture, you will notice that:
a) It is very random and the pattern is not identifiable i.e. it doesn't look like a specific pattern is flowing through the entire texture
b) It is a blend of many many different noises

Comment: I'll try to create this and let you know. dont worry